# Aligning UIButtons to bar plot of a horizontal Core Plot CPTBarPlot

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I'm using Core Plot 0.9 in my first iPad project. I need to create an horizontal bar plot, and to create UIButtons on its left aligned with the center of each bar, one button per bar, cf the attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3lYF.png).

My setup is pretty simple:

I have a custom UIView subclass that acts as a container.
Inside of it, I have 2 subviews: a CPTGraphHostingView and a UIView to contain my UIButtons. 
I host a CPTXYGraph in my CPTGraphHostingView and I assign some paddings values.

In my custom class, I have a method that will create the buttons once the dataSource has been set:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nbRecords; i++) {

    // grab the bar location and create a plot point for it
    NSNumber* loc = [dataSource numberForPlot:plot field:CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation recordIndex:i];
    double plotPoint[2] = {0, [loc doubleValue]};

    // Convert the plot point to plot area space coordinates (I guess ;))
    CGPoint viewPoint = [graph.defaultPlotSpace plotAreaViewPointForDoublePrecisionPlotPoint:plotPoint];

    // Convert the view point to the button container layer coordinate system        
     CGPoint p = [graph convertPoint:viewPoint fromLayer:graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea];

    // Create the button
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, p.y - 11, 100, 22);
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [btn setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];        
    [buttonView addSubview:btn];
    [self addSubview:btn];
    [array addObject:btn];
    [btn release];
}
```

The buttons are created but the alignment is not good... I noticed that if I set all the graph paddings to 0, then the buttons are aligned (but of course I need the padding).

Am I missing something or a step in the conversion of the points ? I am a bit confused on how to convert a plotAreaPoint coordinates to any other UIView ...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured the problem myself. In fact, I was adding the buttons before the graph had a chance to layout itself. Calling the graph's method `-layoutIfNeeded:` just before the loop solved the alignment problem